# Algorithm for traversing directed graph like this (picture inside)

Tags: graph, traversal

I have a graph like this:

[image: graph]

One simple rule:
Every node in the graph only knows about its successor.

As you can see, the problem occurs when we came to `6` (by the first branch, `1 → 6`), so that we do not know when it is time to stop and start traversing another branch (`2 → 6`).

Could anyone suggest an algorithm for traversing graph like this, please?

I came up with the idea when I am traversing `1 → 6 → end of graph`, and then returning to `2 → 6`.
But I think this is not good idea, because there could be a lot of forks on the `1 → 6 → end of graph` way.

Comment: I think you mean to process a node only when all its parent have been processed.

Comment: No knowing the parent is not really a problem because computing the reverse edges is simple: create an empty 'parent' list for all nodes, then for all nodes (what ever order), add its id tho its children's parent list.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, there are only two ways to [traverse a graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal).

1. [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)
2. [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

There are plenty of other options, of course, but these are the simplest and most generally applicable.  The other algorithms can mostly be thought of as variations on these themes anyway.  Choose whichever one is best for your problem and go to town!

Comment: Neither of them will work. DFS: 0,1,6,2,... / BFS: 0 (push 1,2), 1, (push 6), 2 (push 3), 6 ....

Comment: I downvoted your answer, because it don't answer the question. But actually it is still the best answer... I you edit you answer, i'll be allowed to de-downvote it...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  OP didn't give his expected traversal order.  This question is almost two years old, so it's unlikely he's going to update it.

Comment: well, you might be right... I expected the node indices to be the expected traversal order, but maybe I just thought so because this is the problem I am currently facing. Again, if you do any edition, I'll be allowed to un-downvote it. Right now, I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively, you mark each node when you cross it and when there is nothing left to explore you go back.

Something that will look like

```
function 

mark the current edge
for all it's vertices
call the function on the edge that is connected with the vertice if the edge is not marked
do something with the edge (display or whatever)
once there is no vertices left return
```

C example, if the graph is represented by a adjacent matrix, a length of 1000 means there are no vertices.

```
void inDepth(int i)
{
    int j;

    edges[i] = 1; //edges is the marking vector

    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
        if ((vertices[i][j]<1000) && (vertices[i][j]>0) && (edges[j]==0)) 
        {
            inDepth(j); 
        }
    }

    printf("%d ",i);
}
```

Comment: If you want and example in C, just ask.

Comment: And that is either DFS or BFS if you do something with the edge after or before inspecting all vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that a DFS search? ([Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search))

Comment: Breadth first search works, too... I think the OP hasn't described the problem very well.